# There were errors validating the config synchronization

Tags: blocks, configuration

Locally I deleted custom block "CTA" from custom blocks and block types. Then I exported configs and created merge request. After merge is accepted, the pipeline runs commands on the dev server. And after `drush -y cim` command I receive the table which shows what configs were deleted and changed and also the next error:

> [error]  Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporterException: There were errors
> validating the config synchronization. Entities exist of type Custom block and Custom block type CTA. These entities need to be deleted before
> importing. in Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporter->validate() (line 750
> of
> /var/www/html/website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/ConfigImporter.php).

In ConfigImportCommands.php line 360:

> The import failed due to the following reasons:
> Entities exist of type Custom block and
> Custom block type CTA.      These entities need to be deleted
> before importing.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I usually ignore any block content related configurations using config ignore. Blocks are a config pain.

Answer (score 3):

The error message tells you what to do:

> Entities exist of type Custom block and Custom block type CTA. These
> entities need to be deleted before importing.

You can solve this as follows:

1. Delete all blocks of type CTA at Admin -> Structure -> Block Layout -> Custom Block Library
2. Delete the CTA block type at Admin -> Structure -> Block Layout -> Custom Block Library -> Block Types
3. Import the configuration